# Laravel controller needs to determine if ANY input is detected

Tags: php, post, laravel, input, laravel-4

I have created a basic CRUD controller within Laravel for use as a very primitive API. The result is that the same URL is currently used to both view records (entries) from a web browser and also store records via POST. Right now, the way I'm determining if it should store or list all records is to detect a the field 'ip':

```
public function index()
{
    // Store an entry
    if(Input::has('ip'))
    return $this->store();

    // Show entries
    $entries = DesktopEntries::all();
    return View::make('desktopentries')->with('entries', $entries);
}
```

However, it seems that sometimes the application that is sending data will not have IP data. Is there is a simpler way to detect if there is ANY input at all as opposed to checking for a single field? I have close to 25 fields being submitted from various sources and there isn't necessarily a required field among the group.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Input::all()`

```
$data = Input::all();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    if(!empty($value))
    {
        return $this->store();
    }
}
// Show entries
$entries = DesktopEntries::all();
return View::make('desktopentries')->with('entries', $entries);
```

but the best way is to use separate url

Answer (score 0):

Like all great things in life, it seems there are multiple ways to solve this problem. To keep this solution in the controller I used this method to check if POST data was detected in the request. The same could technically be done for GET:.

```
public function index()
{
    if(Request::isMethod('post'))
    return $this->store();

    // Show entries
    $entries = DesktopEntries::all();
    return View::make('desktopentries')->with('entries', $entries);
}
```

This could also be done in the controller by checking to see if the count of Input::all() was greater than 0.

This could also be done via your routes file. Here is my example:

```
Route::get('desktop3', 'DesktopPhController@index');

Route::post('desktop3', 'DesktopPhController@store');
```

Where @store is the function that creates a new record and listens for input.